# Use Vaadin UI in Office 365 Outlook web Add-in

Tags: java, outlook, office365, outlook-web-addins, vaadin6

I am developing Office 365 outlook add in for one of our product that is developed on Java and Vaadin 6 framework. Our Java application has a very complex interface. We are tying to create similar interface in outlook web addin.

Actually what we are trying to achieve is that, we want to use the same Java Vaadin UI inside the outlook web add-in. We do not want to create UI using javascript as the UI of our main Java application it too complex and it keeps changing in different scenarios.

As per documentation, iframe is not allowed inside the add in. So can any one suggest me a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction to create add-in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx

Then put your iframe inside the add-in page, and it works fine.